# How can I faded label in Highchart Timeline if it's not selected?

Tags: highcharts

I have data like this:

```
var data = [{
    x: Date.UTC(1951, 5, 22),
    name: 'First dogs in space',
    label: 'fds',
    dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: false,
        format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
            '</span><br/>{point.label}'
    },
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1957, 9, 4),
    name: 'First artificial satellite',
    label: 'First artificial satellite',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1959, 0, 4),
    name: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
    label: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1961, 3, 12),
    name: 'First human spaceflight',
    label: 'First human spaceflight',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1966, 1, 3),
    name: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
    label: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1969, 6, 20),
    name: 'First human on the Moon',
    label: 'First human on the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19),
    name: 'First space station',
    label: 'First space station',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1971, 11, 2),
    name: 'First soft Mars landing',
    label: 'First soft Mars landing',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1976, 3, 17),
    name: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
    label: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1978, 11, 4),
    name: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
    label: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1986, 1, 19),
    name: 'First inhabited space station',
    label: 'First inhabited space station',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1989, 7, 8),
    name: 'First astrometric satellite',
    label: 'First astrometric satellite',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1998, 10, 20),
    name: 'First multinational space station',
    label: 'First multinational space station',
}];
```

I want when user select on any label that label is highlighted and left all other gonna faded. 
Also what I want in this when I move the cursor on the faded label it's changing label color so that user can click on that label.

I have added Fiddle link below:
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/90kwnp24/)

For your reference.
Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `Custom-Events` plugin: https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events.

**Code:**

```
series: [{
  dataLabels: {
    events: {
      mouseover: function() {
        if (!this.dataLabel.isSelected) {
          this.dataLabel.attr({
            fill: '#efefef'
          });
        }
      },
      mouseout: function() {
        if (!this.dataLabel.isSelected) {
          this.dataLabel.attr({
            fill: '#fff'
          });
        }
      },
      click: function() {
        var point = this.point,
          series = point.series;

        series.points.forEach(function(p) {
          p.dataLabel.attr({
            fill: '#fff'
          });

          p.dataLabel.isSelected = false;
        });

        this.dataLabel.attr({
          fill: 'red'
        });

        this.dataLabel.isSelected = true;
      }
    }
  },
  marker: {
    symbol: 'circle'
  },
  data: data,
}]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u01hyk2x/